# Howto create ATL/C++ ActiveX DLL in Visual Studio 2005

Tags: c++, dll, visual-studio-2005, activex, atl

I need to create an ActiveX DLL (not a control). I know that VB6 was able to create this project, but I would like to write this DLL with C++.
VS2005 doesn't support any project template to create such a component.

I tried to create a COM DLL with ATL, but I'm not sure that it can be considered as an ActiveX DLL.

How can I convert a COM DLL into an ActiveX DLL? Is it just a matter of implement specific interfaces for ActiveX?
Does anyone know which are the differences between a COM DLL, an ActiveX DLL and an ActiveX control?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A COM DLL is the same thing as an [ActiveX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActiveX) DLL.  An [ActiveX control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751968%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is an ActiveX/COM DLL that implements certain common interfaces for hosting in a container application.